# Php keep echo when you submit and add new one

Tags: php, web, statistics

i want to make a add cricket stats page (witch i have done) but when i fill in the form and press submit i made it say `echo "$name stats have been added";` but when i add a new persons stats that dispersers and is replaced by a different the one i just made, how can i make it stay every time i add a new one so i can see who's stats i have added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an array of names stored in `$_SESSION` and keep adding to it on each post. Then display them all each time.

```
session_start();
// Initialize the array
if (!isset($_SESSION['names'])) {
  $_SESSION['names'] = array();
}

// Add the newest name to the array
$_SESSION['names'][] = $name;

// Display them all in a loop with linebreaks
foreach ($_SESSION['names'] as $cur_name) {
  echo "$cur_name stats have been added<br />\n";
}
```

**EDIT:**
To reset them, pass `?action=reset` in the URL querystring as www.example.com?action=reset

```
<form action='scriptname.php' method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
  <input type="submit" value="Reset list" />
</form>

// Remove the session array on reset.
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "reset")
{
   unset($_SESSION['names']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! How can i make a reset button to delete all the saved echo's?

Comment: See edit above. I added a tiny bit to unset the session array.

Comment: If you mean the reset part, it isn't necessary to wrap it in a conditional.  It's already there - the form is submitted as a GET request, and the action parameter is checked.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just insert the new name you wanna add, into your DB ? and make a select when you wanna view some names